# Skipping stones on the surface of a non-static fluid -- how to assess in vector space?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, vectors

While skipping shells at the beach, I
noticed the following:

Waves approaching the shore impede the average velocity of my skip; retreating waves appear to do the opposite.

This, of course, makes sense. The shell should accelerate when striking a surface that is traveling in the same direction (and decelerate when the surface moves oppositely).

However, the inconsistencies in my experimental method are flagrant. Without proper measurements, my interpretations are bias and speculative (not to mention rooted in oversimplified classical intuition).

My question:
Can I use vector operations to properly assess the extent to which a moving fluid impacts an object skipped on its surface?

What would a proper force diagram look like?

What would an accurate theoretical calculation look like (which could be used to accurately predict experimental results in an idealized scenario)?

I'd like to clarify that I am not asking how velocities add in fluid's. I am not asking how stones skip.

For simplicity I am not concerned with accelerating, chaotic currents.
I am only concerned with fluidic surface s moving at constant velocities.

Comment: Could your experimental inconsistencies be due to how close to the crest or the trough the stone initially hits, or if it hits ahead or behind the moving crest? Just some variables to consider. FWIW